# Docker file does not have /bin/bash directory

Tags: bash, docker, heroku, dockerfile, rasa

I have been following [this tutorial](https://shanaka95.medium.com/deploy-your-ai-powered-rasa-chatbot-for-free-on-heroku-ef1ad5e4ae2c) about posting a Rasa chatbot on Heroku using a Docker image.  I am using Windows 10, and I am new to Docker.

When I get to the step `heroku container:push web -a {appname}`, it runs through the Dockerfile, but it outputs the following error:

> container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec:
> "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory

I've tried doing some of the suggestions in other StackOverflow responses like, such as updating ubuntu, installing bash (with apt-get and apk), adding different shebangs.  However, I can't seem to get the Dockerfile to run chmod or any similar commands.  Here is my Dockerfile for reference.

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y bash

FROM rasa/rasa:latest
ADD . /testheroku/
RUN chmod +x /testheroku/rasa.sh
RUN cd /testheroku && rasa train
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD /testheroku/rasa.sh
```

The terminal shows the following process as it builds:

> [+] Building 0.8s (7/8) 
> => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile <br
> => => transferring dockerfile: 32B 
> => [internal] load .dockerignore 
> => => transferring context: 2B 
> => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/rasa/rasa:latest 
> => [internal] load build context 
> => => transferring context: 721B 
> => [stage-1 1/4] FROM docker.io/rasa/rasa:latest 
> => CACHED [stage-1 2/4] ADD . /testheroku/ 
> => ERROR [stage-1 3/4] RUN chmod +x /testheroku/rasa.sh

Does anyone have any thoughts about what I need to do to make this run?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `#! /usr/bin/env bash` in your Dockerfile?

Did you try building your image without that line?

Your Dockerfile should look just like this:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y bash

FROM rasa/rasa:latest
ADD . /testheroku/
RUN chmod +x /testheroku/rasa.sh
RUN cd /testheroku && rasa train
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD /testheroku/rasa.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I tried running the Dockerfile without it, but it still has throws an error when it gets to the chmod line.

Comment: Good, at least we got rid of the "/bin/bash" problem - what's the error now?

Comment: ERROR [stage-1 3/4] RUN chmod +x /testheroku/rasa.sh                         1.6s

Comment: 1.503 container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory

Comment: The two messages above are what it sends back.